# Elusive text exercise (jquery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning jquery/javascript and I did the exercise exactly as the book said. However the span box is not moving on hover as it is supposed to.

If someone could help me find out what I did wrong I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you so much

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/036bz98a/

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <span id="elusiveText" onmouseover="moveIt()">Click Me</span>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    span {
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
left: 100px;
background-color: #0066AA;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
border: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function moveIt(){
var coords = new Array(10,50,100,130,175,225,260,300,320,350);
var x = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))];
var y = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))];
$("elusiveText").css({"top": y + "px", "left": x + "px"});
}
```

And then I linked to the latest jquery library

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The jQuery code you're using to find and update the text element has an incorrect selector. The line should look like:

   ```
   $("#elusiveText").css({"top": y + "px", "left": x + "px"});
   ```
2. In the jsfiddle, you need to set the JavaScript wrapper mode to "No wrap (in body)".

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer and the jsfiddle tip.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong selector and shouldn't wrap method in `onload` function (feature on jsFiddle):

```
function moveIt() {
    var coords = new Array(10, 50, 100, 130, 175, 225, 260, 300, 320, 350);
    var x = coords[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))];
    var y = coords[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))];
    $("#elusiveText").css({
        "top": y + "px",
        "left": x + "px"
    })
}
```

Here [-jsFiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/036bz98a/2/) using `animate()` method instead if that's matter...

Comment: Interesting, I like the `animate()` alternative. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong,

Use # to select element by id like this:

```
$("#elusiveText").css({"top": y + "px", "left": x + "px"});
```